# Is there a way to get Aginity Workbench to write Unix files rather than Windows files (LF only rather than CR\LF)

Tags: netezza, aginity

Is there a way to get Aginity Workbench to write Unix files rather than Windows files (LF only rather than CR\LF)?

"My" developers check their code into SVN on Windows, and then we check it out into a development environment, and it's ... complicated, but doing a tr -d \r on every file on checkout is problematic.

Thanks.

Comment: I don’t expect so, but have you logged a request with the aginity guys? I once had the do a change to support our national keyboard better, and it took only a few weeks at that time, no questions asked...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use dos2unix utility to get proper file encoding?
Anyway, there is Aginity Support portal by the link below. You can submit your question there:
https://support.aginity.com/hc/en-us/community/topics

Comment: One answer is that "dos2unix" isn't installed in our environment, and tr (mentioned in the question) can do the same thing. But the real reason is that *I* can do that, but most of my team are windows folks who are going to have to start doing some of this stuff and it is likely that they won't even use SVN to move the files up--they'll just scp them over. 

Which might be the answer, I'll have to look and see if WinSCP will do file translation. I normally use Cygwin and the commandline ssh, so it's not problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Workbench you can actually recode a text file to convert it from one encoding to another.  Tools menu -> File Utilities -> Re-code a text file.

Comment: The problem is that my devs won't think to do this before checking the code into SVN, and it can occasionally cause some problems on the Unix side (not for nzsql/nzload, but when doing other stuff).